# Django sorl thumbnail cache image path mismatch when using manage.py dumpdata

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to migrate data from staging to local copy of my site.

The images in the media folder are all transferred okay.

Then I use the following command to export my staging site

```
python manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes > db.json
```

I then take the db.json file and load it to my local copy of the django site using the following command.

```
python manage.py loaddata < db.json
```

Some of the images shows up and some don't, after comparing those image tags src between staging and local. I realized that they don't match up.

For example, an image is referencing a file here on the staging site 
/media/cache/a0/83/a083042025374b34c59547e857a4d3fa.jpg

becomes this:
/media/cache/78/c6/78c6f6982cc063cd9f82939037d990a3.jpg

These are generated by Sorl-thumbnail. Anyone knows why??